# Teamviewer vpn install

Tags: vpn, teamviewer

I use ubuntu mate 20.04LTS .And I need teamviewer VPN .I have already installed and run teamviewer .But I couldn't see VPN option.I have to get connect betwwen plc and my pc.Do you know any solution or altertative option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use TeamViewer VPN on Ubuntu, as it is not supported.

Quoting a specific answer on a thread from [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/348349/72074):

> No, the VPN functionality is not currently supported on Linux. They may have plans for it in the future, however.

That was in 2011.  There has been no movement by TeamViewer to support the TeamViewer VPN functionality on Linux since then, which suggests that they do not plan to make TeamViewer VPN work on Linux environments.